# Why am I getting a -1 in getColumnIndex method

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-cursor

```
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
          + DATABASE_TABLE_USERS + "(" + KEY_ROW_ID + 
         " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME
          + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + KEY_ZIP + " TEXT," +
          KEY_STREET + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_PHONE + " TEXT);";
```

I create the database in the on_create method:
       db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

I have this method:

```
 public int getLoginAttempts(String u_name) {

    String [] columns = new String [] {DB_Helper.KEY_NAME};
    Cursor c = database.query(DB_Helper.DATABASE_TABLE_USERS, columns, DB_Helper.KEY_NAME + "= ?",
             new String[] {u_name},
             null,
             null,
             null);

    if(!c.moveToFirst()) return -1;

    int c_index = c.getColumnIndex(DB_Helper.KEY_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS);

    int num = c.getInt(c_index);
    c.close();
    return num;
}
```

c_index always equals -1. This means that the column doesn't exist. But it does. And there should only be one record coming back (for u_names are unique).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

that is because in query you are selecting only name column

replace this line

```
String [] columns = new String [] {DB_Helper.KEY_NAME};
```

with

```
String [] columns = new String [] {DB_Helper.KEY_NAME, DB_Helper.KEY_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS};
```

Comment: when I query a database and get back a cursor, what information does that cursor hold?

Comment: the `columns` array which you passed to `query()` method, it'll hold those column's information only.